# Permission Issues When Running Shell Script From Android App

Tags: shell, android

I am using the following code to run a shell script through an android application. I am able to run the script but only echo command is getting executed. Commands like netcfg, cat, route, setprop are not getting executed. Are there any permissions which I am missing out or any other thing. Please let me know.

```
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String path;
    path="/system/bin/sh /persist/eth0.sh";
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line;

       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println(line);
       }



    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android has its own linux kerneal and does not ship with all common commands found in desktop distros.

Comment: But if i run the same script from the Terminal(adb shell) its running properly without any issues. It's only when I try to run the script through the android app, when many commands don't get executed.

Comment: Following is a command line reference :
https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference

Comment: The link tells about the commands that can be used in shell, as i mentioned before the script runs perfectly fine if run through adb shell, but when i run through the android app it gives issues.